# How do i do a Save operation on a MongoDB collection using the Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I just switch over from Python, and need to continue my work with a MongoDB database. One particular task is to save an incoming document (in this case, a tweet) into a collection for archiving. A tweet could comes in multiple times, so I prefer to use `save()` over `insert()` since the former do not raise an error if the document already exists in the collection. But it seems the Java driver for MongoDB does not support the save operation. Am I missing something?

EDIT: for reference, i'm using this library `'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2'`

Example code:

```
MongoCollection<Document> tweets = db.getCollection("tweets");
...
Document tweet = (Document) currentDocument.get("tweet");
tweets.insertOne(tweet);
```

The last line raise this error when the tweet already exists:

`Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: db.tweets.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('55a403b87f030345e84747eb') }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the 3.x MongoDB Java driver you can use `MongoCollection#replaceOne(Document, Document, UpdateOptions)` like this:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = ...
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDB");
MongoCollection<Document> tweets = db.getCollection("tweets");
...
Document tweet = (Document) currentDocument.get("tweet");
tweets.replaceOne(tweet, tweet, new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
```

This will avoid the duplicate key error. However, this is not exactly the same as using `DBCollection#save(DBObject)`, since it uses the whole `Document` as filter instead of just the _id field. To mirror the old save method, you would have to write something like this:

```
public static void save(MongoCollection<Document> collection, Document document) {
    Object id = document.get("_id");
    if (id == null) {
        collection.insertOne(document);
    } else {
        collection.replaceOne(eq("_id", id), document, new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, can't compile since the method is not there. for reference, i'm using this library 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2'

Comment: Try `org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver`, see my updated answer.

Comment: I updated my answer again. You obviously are using `MongoDatabase` where you should use `com.mongodb.DB`.

Comment: i'm trying to use version 3.x of the driver since that has a more sensible API imho, but so far it looks like `save` is only possible in 2.x :( which is silly. thanks for the answer though, upvoted (gonna keep the question open for a bit more in case someone with new info comes across it)

Comment: I figured out the 3.x way, see my update updated answer.