# update() equivalent for version 3.2

Tags: mongodb

In older versions i could use `collection.update()` to insert/replace a whole document by it's `_id`

It seems that for the new API i'll always have to create the id-filter by myself:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/#Updating-%7B%7Bsave%28%29%7D%7Dinthemongoshell

Is there still a function which inserts the document or replaces if the `_id` already exists?

Comment: Looks like `replaceOne` with `upsert` true is what you need.

Comment: and i'll always have to put the filter `new Document("_id", p._id)` by myself?

Comment: ok that seems to be the intended way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391119/how-do-i-do-a-save-operation-on-a-mongodb-collection-using-the-java-driver#31391229 thanks

Comment: What problems are you having with the [collection.update() command](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/)? It does still exist in v3.2, and hasn't changed since v2.6. Were you previously using a version even older than that?

Comment: because i migrated to the new collections implementation